# Is the win_turns in my code even counting through the loop at this point? I dont believe my code is running either but I am not getting any errors

Tags: python, for-loop

The intention of this code is to run in a loop until a specified amount of turns or until I roll snake eyes(both die are = 1). I am not entirely sure what specifically is not working in my code so far.

```py
import random
def play_game(rolls, win_turns):
    win_turns = 0
    rolls = []
    i = 2
    for _ in range(2):
        roll = random.randint(1, i)
        rolls.append(roll)
        win_turns= win_turns + 1
        i = i + 2
    if roll in rolls == 2:
        return win_turns
```

Comment: it isn't clear to me what you are trying to accomplish? the title of the question doesn't make sense to me with what you've got written in the body of the question here. Is your code doing what you want but you want to know if there is a better way to do it?
To maybe answer the question phrased in the title: you can break out of a loop with the keyword `break`. A loop could have in it `if x == y: break` and you would break the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems here.  Your "loop" only picks the two dice -- you don't loop until a loss.  The "roll in rolls == 2" doesn't mean anything.  This basically does what you ask:

```
import random
def play_game(turns):
    win_turns = 0
    for _ in range(turns):
        die = random.randint(1,6), random.randint(1,6)
        print("Roll:", die )
        if sum(die) == 2:
            break
        win_turns += 1
    return win_turns

print("Wins:", play_game(10))
```

Comment: So this would fulfill running the game once. If I wanted to collect data on say 50 games would I just add a for loop after the print statement or is that something I do inside the function?

Comment: The function runs one game.  If you want to run 50 games, then you need a loop that calls the game once each time.  You'd need to track the results in a list or a sum.  So, as an example, `result = [play_game(10) for _ in range(50)]`.

Comment: If you want to revise your question, then revise your question.  Don't modify my answer.